# Django model filter based on boolean field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have a user model which has fields like these,

```
is_active = models.BooleanField()
date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
resigned_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Where `resigned_date` will be `None` if `is_active` field is `True`. If `is_active` field is `False` then the `resigned_date` field will have the date. I think I can explain it.

What I want is to queryset of users based on some `DATE` and `is_active` field.

More clearly I want to get the list of employee that (is `active` and `joined_date` is less that or equal to the current date) and (is not `active` and `resigned_date` is greater that the current date)

The query I have written so far:

```py
users = user_models.User.objects.filter(
                Q(
                     is_active=True,
                     date_joined__month__lte=month,
                     date_joined__year__lte=year,
                 )
              & Q(
                     is_active=False,
                     resigned_date__month__gt=month,
                     resigned_date__year__gt=year,
                 )
            )
```

But this is not working. It is not returning any users.

How can I achive this?

Thanks

Comment: what is the output for this block of code?

Comment: Nothing. Just a blank querylist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to do this with this below method:

```py
all_users = user_models.User.objects.filter(
                branch_id=branch_id,
                date_joined__month__lte=month,
                date_joined__year__lte=year,
            )

active_users = all_users.filter(
                is_active=True,

            )
inactive_users = all_users.filter(
                is_active=False,
                resigned_date__month__gt=month,
                resigned_date__year__gte=year,
            )
users = list(chain(active_users, inactive_users))
```

If using single query

```py
users = user_models.User.objects.filter(
                Q(
                    branch_id=branch_id,
                    date_joined__month__lte=month,
                    date_joined__year__lte=year,
                ),
                Q(is_active=True)
                | Q(
                    resigned_date__month__gt=month,
                    resigned_date__year__gte=year,
                ),
            )
```